# Tomcat gives 404 error when war file deployed for spring boot multimodule project. it works fine when start in IDE using same tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat

Tomcat gives 404 error when war file deployed for spring boot multimodule project.
it works fine when start in IDE using same tomcat.

code in parent pom

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

code in main file

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ABC extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ABC.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ABC.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World from Tomcat";
    }
}
```

Comment: Which URL are you using to access this?

Comment: i'm working on my local end